# Kali Linux - Can't move or resize any window - Everything is stucked on topbar

Tags: linux, taskbar, kali-linux, bug

I have the following problem.

I've logged into my account and suddenly, all windows and terminals have no taskbar anymore.
So I'm not able to move any windows. Can't even resize it.

Also, when I open Firefox from the terminal and if I try to type in an address in the addressbar, nothing happens. Then I realized, that all the things that I type, are entered into the terminal in the background.

Everything is kinda messed up. I don't use a VM for Kali. I've tried to login into another account and there seems everything fine. So this issue is bound to my main account.

Is there a possibility, to repair my profile? I have so many files and applications there, and I really don't want to reinstall everything. But if there is no other option, I will reinstall everything.

If any information is missing, I will add it.

Yours sincerely
Don

Comment: Try sudo apt autoremove in a terminal window and then restart. This sometimes helps me.

Comment: Thanks for your help at first! But sadly, it didn't worked out.
"sudo apt autoremove" was successfully executed, but after reboot, same issue.

I have a Screenshot here: https://imgur.com/GDWWZfc.png
(Is that the right way to post a picture?)

As you can see on this picture, the windows are kinda connected to the topbar of linux. Also, it's not possible to choose a different workstation. Tried to add the number of workstations, but still the same.

Comment: Can you close Firefox?  That appears to have gone completely full screen.

Comment: I'm able to close firefox, but that doesn't change anything in the end.
I can make another Screenshot of course if needed.

Thanks for the fast reply

Comment: I am not sure. The only Linux User Profile fixes I saw were for Ubuntu and I could not recreate the steps in my Kali system.

Comment: Dang it. But really, thanks for your effort!
It's such a annoying thing.

FYI, I have not installed or changed something on the system that day as far as I know. Just as I mentioned, when I login into another account, it works fine

Comment: I hope someone can help me out with this

Answer (score 5):

Open a terminal and enter

xfwm4

then press enter. This should restart your window manager and recover your buttons.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a couple of years old but I just had the same problem. Not much help on the net but I soon found the answer myself. On the terminal window, Select File, Preferences, Appearance and ensure 'Hide Window Borders' is not selected! You will regain full control of window movement and sizing etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you enable the hide window borders
to disable that :

1. right-click the mouse in the Terminal
2. click on Hide window borders off

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and it was indeed the "hide window borders" that I needed to disable as Mohamed ElBadry suggested.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

YO! they say " we can cut diamond with a diamond "
I got a way to fix it , this is a bug that can be fixed by a bug
step 1

open " Kali hiDPI mode " ,

step 2

tap on " no "

here and you will get your  screen back

terminal:

kali-hidpi-mode

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).